# change max output of Milliseconds from 1000 to 2000 in HTML

Tags: time

I am wondering how to change the time format of natural time from 24 hours 60 minutes 60 seconds 1000 milliseconds to 30 hours 30 minutes 30 seconds 3200 milliseconds in HTML

Comment: Please elaborate. Give an example of what you are you trying to do?

Comment: Its just for my own ammusement, however I would like to have time be shown in HTML, I dont really know how to describe it, I just want to do something different for a RPG game that I am doing with some friends, and with them being major brainiacs and stuff, I want to be able to keep up with them and be able to figure things out

Comment: I am using this website (http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock) to help me get a base line on what i'm trying to do, but from that base line, i'm lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, makes slightly more sense now. Firstly you want this to be done in JavaScript. HTML is markup. If you are saying you wish to change the time format, then I can give you examples of changing the format (i.e.: dd-mm-yyyy to mm-dd-yyyy, and many many other variations). Check this out - there you find [lots of examples](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?600547-JS-date-and-Time-Format). If you want to turn a day into 30 hours, however, then this is a proper customisation you have to do. So basically a timer that adds a new hour each 30 minutes, and a minute each 30 seconds. Not sure if that's worth the effort for amusement purposes only ? You might want to impress your friends with other things ... i.e. how quickly you can down a pint!

Comment: ok, so how would you make it be done in real time, and have it correspond with the constraints of real time?? ie if its 9:44:56:600pm CST real time it would be Xpm in converted time